# Solving differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem to solve but I am losing the plot at the end where I decide  $c=\ln(1) = 0$. (doesn't it)

$  \frac{dy}{dx}   = x^2(6-y), y(0)=5$

Separating Variables gives

$   \int \frac{1}{6-y}  \, dy =\int x^2 dx $

let $u=6-y$

$- \int \frac{1}{u} =\int x^2 dx $

$- \ln(|u|) = \frac{x^3}{3}   $

$- \ln(|6-y|) = \frac{x^3}{3}   $

at x=0, y=5 so

$- \ln(|6-5|) =\frac{0^3}{3}+c$

therefore $c=-\ln(1) = 0$

So $-\ln(|6-y|)=\frac{x^3}{3}$

Where to from here? This is about as far as i can get. Need to brush up on my natural log rules?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically done. If you must solve for $y$, then:
\begin{align*}
-\ln|6-y| &= \frac{x^3}{3} \\
\ln|6-y| &= -\frac{x^3}{3} \\
|6 - y| &= e^{-x^3/3} \\
6 - y &= e^{-x^3/3} &\text{since $y(0) = 5$ implies that $6 - y > 0$}\\
y &= 6 - e^{-x^3/3}
\end{align*}

Comment: Of course. Thanks so much I should have known that but now I will never forget it.